# How can I use 'X' /'clear' button inside an input field to initialize/wipe in ADF/MAF?

Tags: button, oracle-adf, oracle-maf

How can I use 'X' mark like a 'clear' button inside an input field to initialize/wipe default data in a ADF Mobile/MAF application?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

add usage ="search" command in inputText components. it will work in all browser except IE9 and